# Mouseout not triggered when child element is removed

Tags: javascript

I have a dropdown menu with mouseover/mouseout handlers for tooltips. The problem is, if the menu is closed while the mouse is over it, mouseout handler does not fire. I can reproduce it with the following example:

```js
const d1 = document.getElementById("d1");
const d2 = document.getElementById("d2");
let d3 = null;

function toggle() {
  if (!d3) {
    d3 = document.createElement("div");
    d3.id = "d3";
    d1.appendChild(d3);
  } else {
    d1.removeChild(d3);
    d3 = null;
  }
} 
d1.addEventListener("mouseover", () => d1.classList.add("hover"));
d1.addEventListener("mouseout", () => d1.classList.remove("hover"));
d1.addEventListener("click", () => toggle());
```

```css
#d1 { background-color: green; display: inline-block; position: relative; }
#d1.hover { background-color: red; }
#d2 { width: 400px; height: 50px; }
#d3 { position: absolute; width: 400px; height: 300px; background: green; top: 100%; }
```

```html
<div id="d1">
 <div id="d2"></div>
</div>
```

Clicking on the menu to close it causes the dropdown to get stuck in the red "hover" state.

Is there a workaround for this that doesn't involve checking mouse position when the dropdown closes?

Comment: Keep the DOM intact and just set `display: none` or something similar with CSS?

Comment: In fact... just do the hover with CSS altogether? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover

Comment: I need to display a complex tooltip on hover, no way that's gona work with CSS. Display none works, but then I need to have the whole menu (or something with the same dimensions) in the DOM, and the menu is quite heavy.

Answer (score 0):

The DOM isn't resizing `d1` when `d3` is removed, so it still thinks `d1` is being hovered over. You need to manually remove the hover class from `d1` when `d3` is removed, then the DOM will recognize that `d1` has shrunk. Add this to the end of the else statement:

```
d1.classList.remove("hover");
```

```js
const d1 = document.getElementById("d1");
const d2 = document.getElementById("d2");
let d3 = null;

function toggle() {
  if (!d3) {
    d3 = document.createElement("div");
    d3.id = "d3";
    d1.appendChild(d3);
  } else {
    d1.removeChild(d3);
    d3 = null;
    d1.classList.remove("hover");
  }
} 
d1.addEventListener("mouseover", () => d1.classList.add("hover"));
d1.addEventListener("mouseout", () => d1.classList.remove("hover"));
d1.addEventListener("click", () => toggle());
```

```css
#d1 { background-color: green; display: inline-block; position: relative; }
#d1.hover { background-color: red; }
#d2 { width: 400px; height: 50px; }
#d3 { position: absolute; width: 400px; height: 300px; background: green; top: 100%; }
```

```html
<div id="d1">
 <div id="d2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: But then it would remove hover if I click on the menu header, which is incorrect behavior.